# Can't access Azure VM HTTP Web Site from Outside of Azure

Tags: azure, http, virtual-machine

I've setup a VM and installed IIS. I checked that the firewall rules were enabled for HTTP and HTTPS. Furthermore, in Azure Portal, I've enabled the two predefined inbound security network group rules for HTTP and HTTPS.

When in the VM, I can go to localhost and see the default Web page of IIS Default Web Site.

Inbound security rule in Network Security Group
[image: Inbound security rule in Security Group]

Anybody know how to go about figuring out how to make this work?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add port 443 and port 80 to azure VM windows firewall inbound rules.

Comment: That was automatically done when I installed IIS. And, I've confirmed that they are in place and are enabled.

Comment: @Eric Open ports for domain or public ?Please check it:)

Comment: Under scope, it says Local IP address: Any IP Address. And, under Remote IP address: Any IP address.

Comment: Could you please take a screenshot of your vm windows firewall inbound rules about port 80?

Comment: Of which tab should I take a screenshot?

Comment: For test, could you please turn off your vm windows firewall settings？

Comment: Jason, when I turned firewall off, it still did not work.

Comment: Could you please check is there a NSG associate with your virtual network subnet?

Comment: I added a screenshot of it above.

Comment: Thanks, is there a NSG associate with your Vnet subnet?

Comment: Jason, that is it! For some reason I have two NSG in my network. :-( I added the rules to the other NSG and it now works! Thank you for helping.

Comment: For me, I had to set it in the outbound rules. Hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Are the Source port ranges on your inbound rules set to 80/443 or * (i.e. all source ports)?

Try changing them to * with only the destination ports set to 80 or 443 respectively.

Ex:

[image]

Refer [How to open ports to a virtual machine with the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal) for more details.

Comment: The source ports are '*'. This was by default.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to make your site accessible from the Internet.

- Use the public IP address which is associated to the virtual machine's NIC.
- Configure DNS for your VM machine (e.g. web.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com). This DNS is bounded to the associated public IP Address.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/portal-create-fqdn

In your IIS, just configure binding to make sure the incoming request from the Internet is recognized by IIS.

You also need to make sure you have no rule in Network Security Group (NSG) blocking port 80. Or if there is a NSG, you need to create an inbound rule to allow port 80.

Comment: I've tried the public IP address and tried the configured DNS for the VM. Both tries have been unsuccessful. As the mentioned in the original post, I can go to localhost on port 80 and see my site so the binding is fine. Also in my original post, I state that the incoming traffic  is opened for port 80 in the network security group.

Comment: What is the error screen? If you use FQDN you must configure IIS binding. If using public IP address you don't have to do anything else (assume no rule blocks port 80).

Answer (score 0):

I Azure Windows VM, apart from configuring the NSG rule, we should also create a Windows firewall rule to allow inbound TCP connections on the required port. Just RDP into your windows VM, open Windows Defender Firewall and add the rule